# CSS and Safari/Chrome

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, flickr

I've been trying to modify the following menu to make it look indentical in IE, Firefox, and Safari/Chrome but I can't seem to get it to look right in Safari/Chrome.

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?  When viewed in Safari or Chrome, notice that the menu is ignoring the padding.

[View flickr-like menu](http://www.candesprojects.com/downloads/flickr-horizontal-menu/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Padding on elements that are or are displayed as inline. http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/inline/

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `inline` elements `inline-block` in order to get the padding working properly.